# Why are some spring data queries not logged?

Tags: java, spring-data, slf4j

In my spring boot project, I have an Entity where I have declared a few lazily loaded lists, such as:

```
...

@OneToMany(mappedBy="element", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Data01> subList01 = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy="element", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Data02> subList02 = new ArrayList<>();

...
```

In my service method, I have a @Transactional method that finds an entity by id and additionally fetches the lists on demand like so:

```
    @Transactional
    public Element findById(Integer id) {
        Element element = elementRepository.findById(id);
        element.getsubList01();           
        element.getsubList02();  
        return element;
    }
```

which works as expected and returns the entity as well as these two lists.  My question regards the logging of the sql queries.

My logging properties are

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=TRACE
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

The initial sql query that retrieves the Element is logged  properly, but the secondary queries that retrieve the subLists are not.

However, if I use the more traditional method of fetching the lists with the size() method,

```
        element.getsubList01().size();           
        element.getsubList02().size();
```

(that's the only difference) these queries are logged.

Why are the queries logged in the second case but not in the first?  Is there an additional logging property I am missing?

Comment: I think the logging properties are ok. The issue is that executing `element.getsubList01()` alone won't trigger the query execution, but using the list e.g. `element.getsubList01().size()` does it.

Comment: Actually, the result is the same regardless of which method I invoke...  But in the absence of either call, I get a LazyInitializationException -- so somehow the same or similar query is being executed, but in the former case it is not logged!

Comment: If you get `LazyInitializationException` it means you're using the list outside of the transaction. Internally, that list is loaded lazily and needs to maintain a relationship with the `EntityManager` used to manage the connection and query execution.